# Why there is an error bar for a single -number seaborn bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am working on a dataset, in which there are IMDB ratings corresponding to each episode. I am wondering, why is there an error bar on my `sns.barplot`?

There shouldn't be any, because the number is a single number and it's not an aggregation of any series of numbers.

**Note**: I know that I can remove the error bar with `ci=None` parameter. Still, the main bar doesn't end at the determined point.

#### In:

```
pop_eps10 = frnds[['Episode_Title','Stars']].sort_values('Stars', ascending=False).head(10).reset_index(drop=True)
pop_eps10
```

#### Out:

[image]

#### In:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(y=pop_eps10.Episode_Title, x=pop_eps10.Stars, palette='Blues_d')
plt.title('Top 10 High-rated Episodes', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('IMDB Stars', fontsize=13)
plt.ylabel('Episode', fontsize=13)
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(9, 10)
```

#### Out:

[image]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/kaggle-user-content/o/inbox%2F3809469%2F7e27eaf6421d95a617bcf3547f3e5b02%2Fds5.png?generation=1587891583158883&alt=media))</sub>

After setting `ci=None`:

[image]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/kaggle-user-content/o/inbox%2F3809469%2Ff9492d1753a9a3867b7f5b09ea8db6ec%2Fds4.png?generation=1587891493551300&alt=media))</sub>

As you see, although there is no error bar, still the first bar is not ended at 9.7 (according to the table above).

Any opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have two rows of 'The Last One', each with value 9.7 and 9.5. Bar plot will take their average, which is 9.6.